# Block Hashing Data

Tags: block, hash, getwork, nonce

Guys I have a few points that are not clear for me.
1) In the link below it says there are some fields we have to combine and hash. However when I get a work by saying getwork from a pool. What I get is in the below either. The problem is that I cannot find the fields listed in the first link, Version, hashPrevBlock etc.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm

Getwork result.

```
{   'data':'0000000271112b7a1cf8e97b8367102f7e155499bf5c7303cbcdd4360000000000000000427719b35a84bc7732edd34ff3a6278dc4ac0ec2a9544e6088bc0bd719e17a8e52db3b211902666600000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080020000',
'hash1':'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000',
'target':'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffff00000000',
'midstate':'45aebb01c0fdb704ee7d2bbf02665943f50f299ff8bb252e614100065bc5c20c'
}
```

2) It says in the first link "Whenever Nonce overflows (which it does frequently), the extraNonce portion of the generation transaction is incremented, which changes the Merkle root." Should I put extra 32 bits for extranonce?

3) What is the reason reversing the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the link you posted is referring to for the full process of mining, as you would need if you're using an ASIC or some other hardware solution capable of generating 4 gigahashes or more per second. if you're using `getwork`, most of that information is irrelevant and confusing.
2. see (1) above. you don't worry about extraNonce when using getwork; you can just request `getwork` again and get a new `data` string from the server.
3. the reason for reversing the header (actually reversing each 32-bit word in the header) is that *it has already been reversed (converted to little-endian)* before sending it to you and you need to *undo* that reversal, putting it back in big-endian form.

all you need to do when using getwork is:

- convert the `data` to big-endian
- get the sha256 hash of the sha256 hash of the 80-byte header
- if that hash is below the threshold, send your header with current nonce to the server using the appropriate `getwork` RPC call with data
- keep trying again with different nonces each time (the last 4 bytes of the 80 bytes are the nonce)

Comment: you mean the only thing I care about will be the last 4 bytes of the data, right? But whose last bytes, the little-endian one or the other? :)

Comment: it really doesn't matter. typically, at least on x86 computers, people increment the little-endian number, then convert the block to big-endian for hashing. I just use random numbers so I couldn't care less about endianness; just have to make sure to put it in the right order for submission to the server.

Comment: remember, it's the *same* 4 bytes in each case; you're not reversing the 80 bytes, you're reversing every 4 bytes *within* the 80 bytes, so 0x12345678 becomes 0x78563412.

Comment: In the example of 0x12345678 you are reversing every 1 byte chunks within a 4 byte value right? 
0x12345678 = 00010010-00110100-01010110-01111000.    
0x78563412 = 01111000-01010110-00110100-00010010

Comment: yes, that's the idea.